# mpdf cannot generate .pdf file on the server

Tags: php, pdf, server, mpdf

My php code is something like this :

```
$htmlOut = 'Some html code';

include("libraries/MPDF60/mpdf60/mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;

$mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlOut);

$mpdf->Output("filename.pdf",'I');
```

I am using this exact same code on my localhost and everything is working  perfect. I get a .pdf file downloaded. But on trying the same code on the server, this does not work. There is no error shown. Just a blank white page. I am new to using mpdf, and I do not know much about this. Any help, please?

Comment: Please add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your script. This enables all errors being shown. Does that give you anything useful? -- also, check that the `www-data` user (or whatever user PHP is using) has the rights to write to `filename.pdf`.

Comment: How do I check the write permissions on the server? Please guide me.

Comment: Are you sure that your server has all packpage that mpdf requires for working and have the right version of php? [mdf requirement] (http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Requirements)

Comment: @CamilStaps Yep, it worked. Thanks. That piece of code showed me the error. Some of the files were missing from the package. Maybe they were missed out during the upload, though I zipped the whole thing before uploading and extracted onto the server. It is working now. Please leave an answer so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Added as an answer per the OP's request:</sup>

Adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

to the top of your file enables displaying all errors, which always gives useful debugging information.

Do remember to remove this code in production environments though.

Comment: This worked for me. Showed me the errors that some of my files were missing from the package.